# How to sort two separate lists alphabetically without intermediate object?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following problem I'm not sure how to address.

I need to paginate two groups of items (ex Cars and Motorcycles). I need a single list sorted alphabetically, which when clicked is directed to a information page for the item.  This is shown in groups of 10 with a back/next button.

My actual classes have very different sets of properties. I don't want to have a single class for both cars and motorcycles.

Both items have an Id, Name, and Description property, but then the remaining properties are unique (whether it's a Car or Motorcycle item).

What is the best way to group the two lists, sort alphabetically, and then pick the desired items (such as items 11-20 from the merged list)? Right now I am converting all items to a DisplayItem class by doing the following (which works) but is not ideal for large groups of items.

```
IEnumerable<DisplayItem> entities = cars.Select(b => new DisplayItem(b)).Union(motorcycles.Select(a => new DisplayItem(a))).Skip(10).Take(10);
```

What would be the correct way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create an interface that both classes implement that contains the sortable property:

```
interface ISortableItem
{
  string Name { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create an interface with the Id, Name and Description properties, and have the Car and Motorcycle classes implement that interface.

```
public interface IDisplayable
{
    int Id {get; }
    string Name { get; }
    string Description { get; }
}

public class Car : IDisplayable
{
    ...
}
```

Then you could do

```
IEnumerable<IDisplayable> entities = cars.Select(b => (IDisplayable)b).Union(motorcycles.Select(a => (IDisplayable)a)).Skip(10).Take(10);
```